# Terminal does not remember "brew" after exit

Tags: command-line, bash

I installed Brew for Ubuntu, like on their website.

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Then i add the path:

```
test -d ~/.linuxbrew && eval "$(~/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
test -d /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew && eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
test -r ~/.bash_profile && echo "eval \"\$($(brew --prefix)/bin/brew shellenv)\"" >> ~/.bash_profile
echo "eval \"\$($(brew --prefix)/bin/brew shellenv)\"" >> ~/.profile
```

Then i run:

```
 brew install hello
```

To confirm working. This command returns

```
Warning: hello 2.12 is already installed and up-to-date.
```

Then i exit the terminal, open a new terminal and run:

```
brew
```

That returns

```
Command 'brew' not found, did you mean:
```

I use

```
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
```

The bash im using is:

```
/proc/37922/exe -> /usr/bin/bash
```

In bash_profile i see the "test" and echo. What could be going wrong....

Answer (score 1):

**Practical outcome of what is explained below**: add all your variables to `~/.profile` then log out and back in to see them "remembered".

**Understanding what is going on**

Environmental variables you set in the current session are lost when you close the terminal and reopen it.

To automatically make environmental variables available, commands that set them have to be run from proper initialisation files. On Ubuntu, `~/.profile` is read once upon login, i.e. when starting a login shell. `~/.bashrc` is run each time you open an interactive terminal.

On Ubuntu, `.profile` is the appropriate location to set environmental variables that need to be available anytime for the current user. Environmental variables that only need to be available while working at a terminal prompt can be places in `~/.bashrc`.

Ubuntu uses `~/.profile`. Bash, however, first will look for `~/.bash_profile`, then for a file `.bash_login`, and only when these files do not exist, will it look for `~/.profile`.

For reasons I do not understand, you choose to create a `~/.bash_profile` file on your system, then add something to `~/.profile`.

Understand that 1) these files are only executed on login and 2) if you created a `~/.bash_profile`, your `~/.profile` will not anymore be used.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 desktop, fixed this problem by 2 ways:

1. In terminal preference -> profiles -> command -> check Run command as a login sell

or

add `eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"` to `~/.bashrc`,
then `source ~/.bashrc`